# MySQL WHERE IN no result with error

Tags: php, mysql

I'm writing this little import/export class, and whenever I run it, the query fails, stating:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ')' at line 1

This is the query I wrote:

```
SELECT 
    b.voorletters,
    b.voornaam,
    b.achternaam,
    b.tussenvoegsel,
    b.email
FROM
    `fietsvoordeelshop_twc`.`fvs_bestellingen` as b
INNER JOIN
    `fietsvoordeelshop_twc`.`fvs_bestellingen_producten` as bp ON bp.bestelling_id = b.id
INNER JOIN
    `fietsvoordeelshop_twc`.`fvs_producten` as p ON bp.product_id = p.id
WHERE
    p.merk_id IN (3,6)
AND
    p.cat_id IN (1)
GROUP BY b.email
```

The `WHERE IN` clause is being generated using PHP.

This works fine whenever there are results to be found, but if no results are found, the error occurs instead of returning, well, nothing. The query works fine using Workbench and HeidiSQL.

I'm using the old [default MySQL library that comes with PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php).

Any help on this would be great. I tried and tried!

Comment: Please show the PHP code that generates the query.

Comment: Have you check that its not a white-space issue?
Is the result itself used for another query that could be causing the problem?

Comment: You say that the contents of the `IN (...)` is generated by php, and it is possible that it generates an empty `x IN ()` list (Which is indeed a syntax error)?

Comment: try adding merk_id and cat_id in SELECT list i.e. SELECT p.merk_id, p.cat_id....

Comment: Can you dump all queries executed by your script?
Looks like there are another problem query.

Comment: Quite obvious, but still is p.merk_id and p.cat_id int by table design?